# Calculate, if exists $\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{e^{z} - 1}{\sin \bar{z}}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Calculate, if exists

$$\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{e^{z} - 1}{\sin \bar{z}}$$.

I think it does not exist. For counterexemple $z_{1} = x, x\in \mathbb{R}, x\to 0$ and $z_{2} = ix, x\in \mathbb{R}, x\to 0$ came to my mind. It is easy to calculate limit for $z_{1}$ but I got stuck on $z_{2}$. Any hint helps!

Comment: It's asymptotic to $\frac z{\bar z}$ as $z\to0$, and it's easy to show that has no limit.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown True, and the solution is much simpler than the accepted one. You should post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$z=x+iy$$

$$\lim_{z \to 0} \dfrac{e^z-1}{\sin \overline{z}} = \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{e^{x+iy}-1}{\sin (x-iy)}$$

As you suggested, this is:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{e^x-1}{\sin x} = 1$$

but

$$\lim_{y \to 0} \dfrac{e^{iy}-1}{\sin(-iy)} = -1$$

Since you are looking to do the limit without L'Hospital's Rule, here are the steps:

$$\begin{align*}\lim_{y \to 0} \dfrac{e^{iy}-1}{\sin(-iy)} & = \lim_{y \to 0} \left(\dfrac{-iy}{\sin(-iy)}\right)\left(\dfrac{\cos y + i\sin y - 1}{-iy} \right) \\ & = \lim_{y \to 0} \left( \dfrac{-iy}{\sin(-iy)} \right) \left( \dfrac{i\sin y}{-iy} + \dfrac{1-\cos y}{iy}\right) \\ & = \lim_{y \to 0} \left( \dfrac{-iy}{\sin(-iy)} \right) \left( -\dfrac{\sin y}{y} + \dfrac{\sin^2 y}{iy(1+\cos y)} \right) \\ & = \lim_{y \to 0} \left( \dfrac{-iy}{\sin(-iy)} \right) \left( \dfrac{\sin y}{y} \right)\left( \dfrac{\sin y}{i(1+\cos y)} - 1\right) \\ & = \left(\lim_{y \to 0} \dfrac{-iy}{\sin(-iy)} \right) \left( \lim_{y \to 0} \dfrac{\sin y}{y} \right) \left( \lim_{y \to 0} \dfrac{\sin y}{i(1+\cos y)} - 1 \right) \\ & = (1)(1)(0-1) = -1\end{align*}$$

Comment: Can you explain how did you get $$\lim_{y \to 0} \dfrac{e^{iy}-1}{\sin(-iy)} = -1$$, at least first step, because I tried by writing $e^{iy}-1 = \siny + i\cosy$ and $\sin(-iy) = ish(-y) $ which lead nowhere.

Comment: I used L'Hospital's Rule: $$\lim_{y \to 0} \dfrac{e^{iy}-1}{\sin(-iy)} = \lim_{y \to 0} \dfrac{ie^{iy}}{-i\cos(-iy)} = \dfrac{i}{-i} = -1$$

Comment: is there any other way of soving it, because I am not allowd to use L'Hospital's Rule?

Comment: @user560461 I updated the answer to avoid L'Hospital's Rule.

Comment: thanks a lot :)))

Answer (score 1):

Write

$$\frac{e^z-1}{\sin \bar z } =\frac{e^z-1}{z }\cdot \frac{\bar z}{\sin \bar z}\cdot \frac{z}{\bar z}.$$

As $z\to 0,$ the first two fractions on the right both $\to 1.$ But as $z\to 0$ on the real or imaginary axis, the last fraction on the right $\to 1$ or $-1$ respectively. It follows that the given expression fails to have a limit as $z\to 0.$